# Excel Sumifs with reference to a cell

Tags: excel

I want to use the sumifs formula to sum a date range but with a variable date as a reference to a cell ie something along the lines of

`=SUMIFS(Database[Daily Commission],Database[Date],>E2)`

So I want to sum the daily commission where the date is greater than the date in E2. Anybody have any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=SUMIFS(Database[Daily Commission],Database[Date],">"&E2)
```